# Too many levels of symbolic links error when creating the virtual environment during the installation of OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, installation, opencv3.0

I have been trying to install OpenCV3 using this installation guide: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/ . I get an error when I try to create the virtual environment using `mkvirtualenv cv`.

I am using a Mac running on Yosemite 10.10.5

The error given is the following:

myuser = is the username of the user im using in my laptop

```
New python executable in /Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module> 
sys.exit(main())

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 708, in main 
symlink=options.symlink)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 921, in create_environment
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1214, in install_python
shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)

File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

IOError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python2.7'
```

I am new to python and I haven't been able to make sense out of this error. Can anyone explain to me what this error means or give me a solution that would be great.

Thank you in advance!